# Android : How to change animation speed dynamically?

Tags: android, android-animation

i have a transition animation xml

```
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="400"/>
</set>
```

I want to apply this animation on several items but with varying duration. I'm trying to dynamically change duration by calling setDuration and then calling startAnimation.

```
mSlideLeft.setDuration(400);
view1.startAnimation(mSlideLeft);

mSlideLeft.setDuration(500);
view2.startAnimation(mSlideLeft);

mSlideLeft.setDuration(600);
view3.startAnimation(mSlideLeft);
```

but all view animation in same duration. How do I dynamically change duration of animation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using the same `Animation` object for all three `Views`. So you're calling `setDuration` on the same object 3 times.

You need to create three separate `Animation` objects if you want to use three different durations.

```
Animation firstSlideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_left);
firstSlideLeft.setDuration(400);
view1.startAnimation(firstSlideLeft);

Animation secondSlideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_left);
secondSlideLeft.setDuration(500);
view2.startAnimation(secondSlideLeft);

Animation thirdSlideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_left);
thirdSlideLeft.setDuration(600);
view3.startAnimation(thirdSlideLeft);
```